# Why is my android app not able to write to FIRESTORE

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a simple UI app to write to Firestore but the OnSuccess or OnFailureListeners don't seem to trigger I have tried reconnecting to Firebase multiple times and also followed some Stackoverflow threads but I don't seem to be able to solve my issue and there is no error with Internet connection as I have already checked that multiple times...using Connectivity Manager.
Code:-

```
private fun updateDatabse(num: String, titleexp: String, gorl: String) {
          val user= hashMapOf(
              "title" to titleexp,
               "expense" to num,
              "gorl" to gorl
          )
//I have tried to enable network as well but it does not update anydata to to Firestore
//        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().enableNetwork()
        val firestore= Firebase.firestore
        firestore.collection("users").document(titleexp).set(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"User added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener(){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Failed!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

[image]

My Security rules are as follows:-

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:-
Logcat till now:-

```
2023-07-14 21:42:25.431   458-499   FA                      com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  Connected to remote service
2023-07-14 21:42:25.432   458-499   FA                      com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  V  Processing queued up service tasks: 5
2023-07-14 21:42:28.108   458-458   TextInputLayout         com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
2023-07-14 21:42:28.121   458-458   TextInputLayout         com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
2023-07-14 21:42:28.244   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:28.296   458-495   chatty                  com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  uid=10153(com.example.budgettrackerusingfirestore) RenderThread identical 2 lines
2023-07-14 21:42:28.301   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:28.332   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:28.346   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:28.349   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:29.336   458-458   AssistStructure         com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  Flattened final assist data: 3512 bytes, containing 2 windows, 24 views
2023-07-14 21:42:30.555   458-499   FA                      com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  V  Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2023-07-14 21:42:40.286   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:40.294   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:40.311   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:40.330   458-495   chatty                  com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  uid=10153(com.example.budgettrackerusingfirestore) RenderThread identical 2 lines
2023-07-14 21:42:40.344   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:40.360   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:41.220   458-495   chatty                  com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  uid=10153(com.example.budgettrackerusingfirestore) RenderThread identical 2 lines
2023-07-14 21:42:41.284   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:41.285   458-495   OpenGLRenderer          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  endAllActiveAnimators on 0xc88bd380 (DropDownListView) with handle 0xc8897060
2023-07-14 21:42:41.297   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.192   458-523   DynamiteModule          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
2023-07-14 21:42:42.199   458-523   DynamiteModule          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
2023-07-14 21:42:42.199   458-523   ProviderInstaller       com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
2023-07-14 21:42:42.214   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2023-07-14 21:42:42.238   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.238   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.238   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.238   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.241   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.241   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.244   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.245   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.246   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.248   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.253   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.254   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.254   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.255   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.256   458-458   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.257   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2023-07-14 21:42:42.286   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.288   458-495   OpenGLRenderer          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  endAllActiveAnimators on 0xdcd1a400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xc8897060
2023-07-14 21:42:42.289   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2023-07-14 21:42:42.294   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2023-07-14 21:42:42.301   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
2023-07-14 21:42:42.306   458-495   EGL_emulation           com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xebba5c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcc8c260)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.309   458-471   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 30041(1197KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 3443KB/4066KB, paused 612us total 159.973ms
2023-07-14 21:42:42.309   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on HeapTrim for 7.508ms
2023-07-14 21:42:42.310   458-523   ProviderInstaller       com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
2023-07-14 21:42:42.311   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.328   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.329   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.331   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.331   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.331   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.333   458-523   NativeCrypto            com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  V  Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
2023-07-14 21:42:42.355   458-523   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.358   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.358   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.392   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.396   458-523   ProviderInstaller       com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  I  Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
2023-07-14 21:42:42.404   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.408   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.415   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.447   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.447   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.447   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.447   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.450   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.454   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.456   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.460   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.466   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.471   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.472   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2023-07-14 21:42:42.491   458-562   rusingfirestor          com...e.budgettrackerusingfirestore  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Comment: Are you sure this function is being called? How are you calling it?  Have you tried logging something just before and after the query is made to know what's happening?

Comment: I'm sure that the function is being called as the debugger comes to it and as for logging I'm only using Firestore to save data without using any authentication

Comment: It sounds like the app/code is not connecting to the database server. You might want to check if your `google-services.json` file is up to date, and if any errors show in your logcat output.

Comment: I actually updated my google-services.json a bunch of times since if you look into my Stackoverflow account I got to know that deleting it and connecting again with Firebase Assistant restores the connection with Firebase but since ".info/connected" is not available in Firestore and then too I tried the same method of deleting the json and then closing Android Studio to reconnect using assistant but, it still does not seem to do it as data was still not updating to Firestore :(

Comment: try creating a empty `users` collection manually in the firebase console..

Comment: Okay I'll do that

Comment: Does not seem to help or do anything also I found something in the logcat which is:- Inactivity, disconnecting from the service. I searched for this error on the internet and someone explained "that no one has asked Firebase Analytics to do anything for a while so it's disconnecting from its service until someone does. That's normal, especially if your app isn't making calls to FirebaseAnalytics"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just worked!! The data is updated to Firestore. I just changed from the Pixel Emulator I use to my physical Samsung device Idk why running the app on that suddenly makes it work but it just did miraculously. Even though the emulator was connected to the internet.
Edit:- Using a physical device instead of an emulator solved the issue as the emulator was unable to add data to Firestore

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).